# Complete Telugu translation of Agni purana

Tags: resource, telugu, agni-purana

I searched several websites and did not find any complete translation of Agni Purana in Telugu.

Is there any publicly available and complete Telugu translation of Agni Puran?

Comment: [kamakoti site](https://www.kamakoti.org/telugu/) and Tirumala ebooks too don't have Agni Purana although they have other Puranas.

Comment: maybe https://pravachanam.com has upanyasas

Comment: Thanks, @mar, I will check...

Answer (score 0):

I think Agni Purana in telugu is available [here.](https://greatertelugu.org/agni-puranam-telugu/)

Answer (score 0):

https://tirumalaebooks.blogspot.com/2020/10/all-puranas-download-in-one-click-ttd.html here all puranas in telugu are present

Comment: They are not complete versions.